# Powershell profile config

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Cant modify $PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost

`"Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"`

> E212: Can't open file for writing: no such file or directory

Actually `cd $PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost` cannot find path because it doesn't exist

Comment: What is your question? How to create a new PowerShell_profile.ps1 file?

Comment: @Theo yes and if it's possible using neovim

Comment: Make the directory first.

Comment: You can just use: `New-Item $PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `New-Item: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\maksm\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'.` UPD: Solved, thank you